# Excel VBA: SQl query of csv file is returning integer instead of double

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv, ado

In Excel, I have VBA code that uses ADO to create a query for a csv file.  The query returns some select fields into a Recordset, which I then extract the data I need for a report.  The field contains string and numerical values.

The code works fine whenever the first numerical value in the field is a double, but if the value is an integer all numerical values are converted to integers, which doesn't give me the results I want.

Here is how I set up the query and get the Recordset:

```vb
Private Function getRecordSet(ByVal fileSource As String, ByVal fileName As String) As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    'set up connection to file source
    con.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    con.ConnectionString = _
        "Data Source=" & fileSource & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;"""
    con.Open
    con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con

    'set up and execute query
    cmd.CommandText = _
        "SELECT [Total Test Timer], [Stage], [Corrected Blowby] " & _
        "FROM " & fileName & " " & _
        "WHERE [Stage] = 1"
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    'disconnect the record set from the file source
    rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    'clean up ADO objects
    Set cmd = Nothing
    If Not con Is Nothing Then
        If con.State = adStateOpen Then con.Close
        Set con = Nothing
    End If

    'return Recordset
    Set getRecordSet = rs

End Function
```

Here is a sample dataset where the code works as expected (The field where the error occurs is 'Corrected Blowby':

```
Total Test Timer,Stage,Corrected Blowby
,,LPM
,,SC1Mod4/ai25
1.04167,1,21.85
1.05,1,21.85
1.05833,1,35.48
1.06667,1,35.48
1.075,1,35.48
1.08333,1,35.48
1.09167,1,35.48
```

And here is a sample dataset where all the numerical values are converted to integers:

```
Total Test Timer,Stage,Corrected Blowby
,,LPM
,,SC1Mod4/ai25
1.025,1,0
1.03333,1,0
1.04167,1,0
1.05,1,0
1.05833,1,21.43
1.06667,1,21.43
1.075,1,21.43
```

I've tried casting the 'Corrected Blowby' field into a string and a double:

```
"SELECT [Total Test Timer], [Stage], cStr([Corrected Blowby]) AS newField " & _
```

And:

```
"SELECT [Total Test Timer], [Stage], cDbl([Corrected Blowby]) AS newField " & _
```

but neither worked.  Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?  Thanks!

Comment: There's not a lot of great options here. You can use (I believe) a schema.ini file to explain the schema of the csv so `jet` doesn't have to guess. I've also read that you can monkey in registry to tell the driver to scan the entire file (instead of a sample) to determine data types by setting `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text\MaxScanRows` to 0.

Comment: Also, and this is ridiculous, but if you are desperate.... I've opened the file and injected fake data into the first 10 or so rows. That fake data contains formats that cause the engine to determine the correct data type. I then filter those records out in the `WHERE` clause. Again, it's ridiculous, but it will get you out of registry edits and schema.ini file writing and maintenance if you are needing to distribute the application.

Comment: I just tried using a Schema.ini file and that works; thanks for the response.  Since the application will be distributed and there are multiple csv files in the source directory, I'm thinking of having the VBA code write an ini file, run the query, and then delete the ini file.

Comment: I answered a similar question to this before. Maybe it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183499/4839827